# Normally vs. in a normal way

Tags: expressions, phrase-choice

> - If you want to attract attention, WRITE IN UPPER CASE; otherwise, write normally.
> - If you want to attract attention, WRITE IN UPPER CASE; otherwise, write in a normal way.

I don't understand which version is correct or sounds more natural.

The examples above are just examples. It could be better to look at the real text:

> If a continuation line is a part of the header of a block, indent it by two levels; otherwise, indent it {**normally**|**in a normal way**} (i.e., by one level).
>
> ```
> if (some_variable == "foo"
>         && some_another_variable == "bar) {  // Indented by two levels
>     DoSomething()
> }
> ```
>
> ```
> DoSomethingElse(Argument1, Argument2,
>    Argument3)  // Indented by one level
> ```

ps. {normally|in a normal way} can be omitted, but it doesn't answer the question :)

Comment: I'd prefer "normally," but neither sounds especially odd to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a realistic situation neither is more correct or natural than the other. However there is a very nit-picky difference between the two which can make "write in a normal way" slightly ambiguous.

- "*...write in a normal way*" uses the indefinite article "a". This implies that there may be multiple normal ways in which it is possible to write, as opposed to using "the" in which it would be clear that there is only one "normal" way of writing.
- "*...write normally*" doesn't use any article so whether there are multiple or a single way of writing normally is dependent on the context.

"If *something* then do *this*, otherwise do *this*" is an either-or relationship. That is, there are only two options available and they are mutually exclusive. Because "writing normally" is one of the two options, and we don't want to confuse the reader by suggesting that there are more than two options being presented, we would prefer to phrase it in a way that implies there is only one normal way of writing.

Thus:

- "*write in **a** normal way*" would be understood by everyone, but in a technical sense the meaning might be slightly unclear.
- "*write in **the** normal way*" is more clear than the previous option, but is slightly wordy.
- "*write normally*" is clear and uses fewer words.

In everyday speech and writing both would be understood equally, but "*write normally*" is more likely to be used as it rolls off the tongue a little more easily.

Comment: This is just amazing. Thanks so much.